# send http request multipart to upload file to seaweedfs using node.js

Tags: node.js, request, multipartform-data

I am currently using seaweedfs as file server. In seaweedfs api document, I need to send a HTTP multipart PUT or POST request. But looks like i did a wrong thing with multipart.

```
>  var formData = {
>       file: file,
>     };
>     var fsUrl = fsServer+'/'+fid;
>     request.post({url: fsUrl, formData: formData}, function optionalCallback(err, httpResponse, body) {
>       if (err) {
>         return console.error('upload failed:', err);
>       }
>       else if(httpResponse.statusCode==200){
>         console.log('Upload successful!  Server responded with:', body);
>       }
>       else{
>         console.log('Upload failed! '+httpResponse.statusCode);
>       }
>     });
```

But I kept receiving status code 301. I don't know why. Is there anyone can help me solve this problem?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

The fid should be on a different volume server. 301 means redirection. You need to post to a different volume server as specific in the http response.

Comment: But I only have one volume server. Then what happend to it